# gradle check fails in travis-ci

Tags: java, gradle, travis-ci

I've added `travis-ci` to my [github project](https://github.com/bduisenov/mockserver). Project itself is multi-moduled and consists of `:client`, `:server` and `:shared`.
In the [build.gradle](https://github.com/bduisenov/mockserver/blob/master/client/build.gradle) of `:client` module I have organised `sourceSets` as follows:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            runtimeClasspath += project(":shared").sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
            srcDirs += project(":shared").sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when `travis-ci` runs `gradle check` it fails with [following](https://travis-ci.org/bduisenov/mockserver/builds/129135801):

```
$ gradle server:clean server:check
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/home/travis/build/bduisenov/mockserver/client/build.gradle' line: 55
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':client'.
> Could not find method main() for arguments [build_ab0sue8nexlysud7wfupu5ddr$_run_closure4_closure12@3fb9a67f] on project ':client'.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 10.05 secs
The command "gradle server:clean server:check" exited with 1.
```

Although running locally, I have no issue with it.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: You need to add the gradlew file and its gradle directory containing the gradle-wrapper.jar  as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the error simply comes from the gradle version on Travis CI using an old version 2.0. If you generate your `gradle wrapper` first then Travis CI will use that instead of the built in version - See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java#Projects-Using-Gradle. I did try your project locally and there is no problem on Gradle 2.12.